# how do i make a node go from one side of the screen to the other?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, screen, nodes

I'm just starting in sprite kit and have hit a road block. I'm trying to recreate the old atari game asteroids. I'm currently trying to find out how to move the node "ship" from one side of the screen and come out the opposite side. An example of this would be pacman going from the right side of the screen and out the left side of the screen. Help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance,
Jared

```
     import SpriteKit

        class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

        let base = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Base")
        let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
        let ship = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ship")
        let shoot = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shootButton")

       override func didMoveToView(view: SKView){

    //        var DynamicView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100))
    //        DynamicView.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
    //        DynamicView.layer.cornerRadius=2
    //        DynamicView.layer.borderWidth=2
    //        self.view!.addSubview(DynamicView)

        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0)

        self.addChild(base)
        base.position = CGPointMake(-350, -200)

        self.addChild(shoot)
        shoot.position = CGPointMake(350, -200)

        self.addChild(ball)
        ball.position = base.position

        self.addChild(ship)
        ship.position = CGPointMake(20, 47)
        ship.xScale = 0.7
        ship.yScale = 0.7

        ship.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        ship.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        ship.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        ship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ship"), size: ship.size)


        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)



        ball.alpha = 0.4
        base.alpha = 0.4


    }





//    func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
//       /* Called when a touch begins */
//        
//        for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
//            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
//            
//            
//                    }
//    }



    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in (touches ) {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let v = CGVector(dx: location.x - base.position.x, dy: location.y - base.position.y)
            let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx)

            let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / M_PI)


//            print( deg + 180)


            let length:CGFloat = base.frame.size.height / 2

            let xDist:CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.57079633) * length
            let yDist:CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.57079633) * length

            ball.position  = CGPointMake(base.position.x - xDist, base.position.y + yDist)

            if CGRectContainsPoint(base.frame, location) {
                ball.position = location
                }
                else{
                 ball.position  = CGPointMake(base.position.x - xDist, base.position.y + yDist)
                }
       ship.zRotation = angle - 1.57079633

            ship.physicsBody?.mass = 2




            var shipRotation : CGFloat = ship.zRotation
            var calcRotation : Float = Float(angle - 1.57079633) + Float(M_PI_2);

            let intensity : CGFloat = 2000.0 // put your value
            let xVelocity = intensity * CGFloat(cosf(calcRotation))
            let yVelocity = intensity * CGFloat(sinf(calcRotation))
            let vector : CGVector = CGVectorMake(xVelocity, yVelocity)

            //Apply force to spaceship
            ship.physicsBody?.applyForce(vector)


        }

    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


        let move:SKAction = SKAction.moveTo(base.position, duration: 0.2)
        move.timingMode = .EaseOut
        ball.runAction(move)


    }
}

//    overridefunc update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
//        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
//    
//}
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Please add more details.

Answer (score 1):

In `func update(currentTime)` check if `ship.position.x < 0` or `ship.position.x > scene.width`. If `true`, set `ship.position.x` to the opposite side.

Comment: thank you for you advice. I will test it out. Much appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using physics to move the ship (as opposed to updating its position by a certain amount in the `update()` method)

So what you could do is to override the `didiSimulatePhysics()` method (which is called after the SpriteKit game engine has done all the physics calculations and moved all the nodes) and if your ship is off screen (which you could do by seeing if it's position is outside the screne's x & y boundaries, or by using the intersectsRect method to see if. The ship's frame no longer overlaps the screen frame) and if it is, simply wrap it to the other side of the screen.